# Zero padding / median filtering

Tags: image-processing, filtering, median

I'm trying to implement median filtering using image j .
I am having trouble with the zero padding as it adds extra zeros to the bottom and far left of the picture.

This is what I have done so far, if you guys can help me out:

```java
Dialog.create("9x9 median filtering");
Dialog.addMessage("9x9 median filtering");
Dialog.show();
setBatchMode(true);

median_filter_9();

setBatchMode("exit and display");

// Produce the 9x9 median image
function median_filter_9() 
{
 width = getWidth();
 height= getHeight();

 //if you want to apply this median filter to 16bit 
 depth = bitDepth();
 nBin= pow(2, depth);
 //nBin hold max gray intensity value 
 filteHisto = newArray(nBin);
 //filteHisto = newArray(255);

 fiveBYFive = newArray(81);
 //this is what i used for middle position of array to get median
 middlePos = round(81/2);


//-3, -3 will get you position 0,0 of a 9x9 matrix if you start in the middle
 for(j=-2;j<width-2;j++){
  for(i=-2;i<height-2;i++){ 
   z=0;
   for(r=0;r<9;r++){
    for(c=0;c<9;c++){
     //Extend outside image boundaries using zero padding.
    //error here: adds extra to bottom and farleft of picture
     if(j+r<0||j+r>=width||i+c<0||i+c>=height){
      fiveBYFive[z]=0;
      z++;
     }else{  
      v = getPixel(j+r,i+c);
      fiveBYFive[z]= v;
      z++;
     }
    }
   }
   //sort the array to find median
   Array.sort(fiveBYFive);
   median = fiveBYFive[middlePos];
   setPixel(j, i, median);
  } 
  updateDisplay();
 }



}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive.  You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen.  As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem.   (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Comment: I second @OliCharlesworth. Let us know if you need further help!

Comment: @OliCharlesworth i have finished  wrting the code but i am stuck on the zero padding, we dont have tutors here so thats y i am asking for help

Comment: How about doing your CS373 assignment by yourself, like the rest of your class?

Comment: I use ping-pong (mirror) padding, which means that as you approach the edge you get double representation of a progressively larger portion of the edge pixels, but nobody gets more than two (except in corners).  I never really thought about how fair that was, but it was a heck of a lot easier than rewriting my kernel to select different indices.

Answer (score 0):

One problem you're seeing at the edges of your image is because you are padding your 9x9 window with zeroes ok, but you still take the median value as the middle of the 81 item window.

So, for example, in the first column of the image, you zero-pad at least 36 elements (more at the top and bottom), which means that you only need to find 4 or 5 more zero pixels in the image to make the median element zero.

The easiest fix is to adjust your median element's index (initialised to 81/2 on each iteration) upward according to how many zeroes you added, or just count how many non-zero pixels you used and then find the median mid-way through that range in your sorted array (taking account of sort order).

In this way, you take the median value of the actual pixels you found and ignore the padded zeroes.

Probably, you missed changing your code from the original 5x5 to 9x9, because the start/end indices are in any case wrong and should be

```java
   for(j=-4;j<width;j++){
     for(i=-4;i<height;i++){
```

The other possible source of confusion later is with this line, where it looks like you've confused width and height

```java
if(j+r<0||j+r>=width||i+c<0||i+c>=height)
```

If `j` is the column index and `i` is the row index, it should be

```java
if(j+c<0||j+c>=width||i+r<0||i+r>=height)
```

Although for a square window this doesn't actually make any difference in practice.